# watch divx on linux CentOS-5.4

Tags: centos

The question itselft tells a lot, can anybody tell me how or point me to the right tutorial? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at VLC:

http://videolan.org/vlc

It's an excellent, cross-platform media player that supports many formats.

There's also a good program called MPlayer (google will find it) but in my experience it's less user-friendly :)

Comment: I don't see anywhere centos on the supported os list, which of these should I try ? 

Debian GNU/Linux
Ubuntu
Mandriva Linux
Fedora
openSUSE
Red Hat Enterprise Linux
Slackware Linux
ALT Linux
Arch Linux

Comment: You want Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 - essentially the same as CentOS 5.  You should be able to add RPMforge to your yum repositories and download/install VLC via yum.  There seems to be some good documentation for that here: http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge/Using

Comment: because red hat enterprise linux (rhel) and centos are binary compatible, software which is certified for rhel will also run on centos.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CentOS 5 multimedia how-to at http://sklav.com/node/2.

Answer (score 0):

To play them with the included media player Totem:

Install the [RPM Fusion free and non-free repositories](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration).

Then install these packages:

```
yum install gstreamer-plugins-bad gstreamer-plugins-ugly -y
```